ODBC Firebird driver not yet implemented
Is there anyone who experienced this error?

SQLSTATE = HY000 [ODBC Fire bird driver] not yet implemented.

What could be the reason why I encounter this error?
Any recommendation how I can solve this?

To be fair the error seems to describe the issue. you are accessing an ODBC connection that seems to point to a firebird database, and the ODBC driver has not been installed, or is not supported in your current setup.

Hi CobyC, Thank you for your response, I already installed ODBC driver for firebird and also, the firebird installer but same error occurs.

Is the error exactly as quoted, because I'd think that a real Firebird ODBC driver would know that Firebird is one word, not two words (Fire and bird). In any case, the error suggests that you're doing something or calling functionality which is not yet implemented. So please provide a [mre], and specify which driver (including its version) you are using, and what you are doing.

Are sure in the error message? "ODBC Fire bird driver" is not official driver's identification string so you must be using other driver or a fork. About the error itself: you are calling a function or ask for operation that is not implemented in the driver. There are a lot of them. Which ODBC call is failing and which are parameters?
